Using slices with scanner and valuer functions
I'm trying to use Scanner and Valuer functions to aid in writing an array of objects to a Postgres database. (I'm very, very new to Go in general.)
package foo

import (
    "database/sql"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    _ sql.Scanner   = (Foos)(nil) // where Foos is an alias type for []Foo, and Foo is an object
    _ driver.Valuer = (Foos)(nil)
)

const NullStr = "null"

func (d Foos) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == NullStr {
        return nil
    }

    bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSONB value: %+v", value)
    }

    result := Foos{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &result)
    d = result
    return err
}

func (d Foos) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(d)
    return string(b), err
}

However, I get an error of "invalid receiver type invalid receiver type []Foo".

You wrote: Foos is an alias type for []Foo. Please be more specific and include the declaration of Foos (I'm guessing type Foos = []Foo) in your question.
Be aware that the receiver of your method cannot be an alias of a type that isn't declared in the same package as the method. With type Foos []Foo, you would be allowed to declare methods whose receiver is Foos in the same package.
